# Why is this Projectile Script Continuing to Hit Targets After I've Destroyed It?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity2D. I am trying to make castle defense game. When the spawners start to inheritance the enemies overlap (they should), but when the archer arrow collides whit the enemies it kills them all. I searched everywhere for the answer of this but nothing...
My questions is:
**Is there a way to only hit one target at time?**

Arrow script:

```
void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").GetComponent<Transform>();
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speedProjectile * Time.deltaTime);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{ 
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    
}
```

Enemy script:

```
 void Start()
{
    
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("target3").GetComponent<Transform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("arrow"))
    {  
        EHealth -= HDamage;
    }
    if (EHealth <= 0) 
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

Comment: Post the code that's detecting the collisions as well as the code that's dealing any damage or handling the "killing" of anything.

Comment: Posted the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. First of all the script is dealing damage so I should hit the target specific number of times, so I can't stop the collision of the arrow without turning it back on. So I made a method, that is being Invoked (InvokeRepeating()) after the arrow collides, that turns a bool back to false. Which method (function) of course should be in Update();
I am not sure if I am saying it right bc I am a beginner but I hope this helps somebody. :D
And here is the code:
Arrow Script:

```
 private void DealDamage()
{
    if (hit == true)
        return;
    eHealth.EHealth -= hDamage.HDamage;
    hit = true;
}
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{ 

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        DealDamage();
        Destroy(gameObject); //Destroying arrow on collision
    }

}
private void HitSetter()
{
    hit = false;
}
void Update()
{
    InvokeRepeating("HitSetter", 0f, 1.1f);
}
```

Enemy Script:

```
 void Update()
{

    if (EHealth <= 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("EnemyDie", true);
        Destroy(gameObject, 0.833f);
    }
```

Also thanks to @Foggzie

Answer (score 1):

Your enemies are all taking damage because destroying a `GameObject` isn't something that happens immediately (for good reason).  Because of this, in a single frame, any number of enemies can be hit by the same arrow.

If you'd like to rely on these collision methods, I'd suggest controlling the damage from the arrow instead of from the enemy, so you can be sure it only hits something once:

```cs
private bool dealtDamage = false;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {  
    // Only deal damage once
    if (dealtDamage) { 
        return; 
    }

    // Does the thing I hit have this "EnemyScript" ?
    var enemy = col.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<EnemyScript>();
    if (enemy == null) {
        return;
    }
     
    // Make this "DealDamage()" method public on your EnemyScript
    enemy.DealDamage();
    dealtDamage = true;
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Then get rid of the Enemy Script's `OnTriggerEnter2D` because the arrow is handling it all.  I don't know what the name of the script is on your enemies so I just called it `EnemyScript`.  This is also calling a `DealDamage()` method that you'd have to make (which would probably look a lot like the one you current have listed in your "Enemy Script.")

Comment: Now it says error: An object of a type convertible to 'bool' is required
and 'ArrowProj.OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider): not all code paths return a value

Comment: `public bool dealtDamage = false;

    private bool OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider col)
    {
        dealtF.DealDamage();
        if (dealtDamage)
            return;
        

        var enemy = col.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<EnemyMoveCS>();
        if(enemy == null)
        
            return;
        
    }`

Comment: This is what I did. I made the `bool dealtDamage` public bc I have to access  it in the EnemyScript.

Comment: Enemy script: `public void DealDamage()
        {
        dealtD.dealtDamage = true;
        EHealth -= hDamage.HDamage;
        
           if (EHealth <= 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }`

Comment: Are there any other methods to do this?

Comment: @VasilKirilov the return type of `OnTriggerEnter2D` should be `void`, not `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say with the information given, based on what you have said it seems that all the entity's are just 1 entity(so when you kill 1 enemy you kill the only enemy which is all of them). you can have them run independently from each other.

Comment: The spawners spawn clone enemies different game object so they are not one single unit.  But the arrow somehow manages to collide with every collider when they overlap (they should overlap). And I am searching for a way for the arrow to collide with only one collider (enemy) kill it (destroy the game object) and then procced with the other enemies..

Comment: Posted some code above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use collision enter function to check bullet is hitting enemy's body.
You can use this code below...

```
private bool isEntered = false;
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(isEntered) return;
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "enemy") isEntered = true;
    ....
    ....
}
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Not working....